# Преобразование double to int

Tags: c++

Вопрос приведения типов.

```
double var = -inf; // or +inf
auto integer = static_cast<uint32_t>(var);
```

Какое значение будет в  переменной integer, это описано в стандарте?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Согласно Стандарту, для C [это приведет к UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986893/5533854)

> 6.3.1.4 Real ﬂoating and integer
>
> When a ﬁnite value of real ﬂoating type is converted to an integer
> type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the
> value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
> cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is
> undeﬁned.50)

Для C++ аналогично:

> [7.3.11](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1)
>
> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
> integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
> is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
> be represented in the destination type**. [Note: If the destination type
> is bool, see [conv.bool]. — end note]